# CalDav Baikal лишние пробелы в ответе

Tags: c#

Пишу приложение для календаря, в качестве сервера установил `Baikal`
Написал добавление и поиск событий
но с поиском возникла проблема. Когда сервер возвращает ответ, в теге `<cal:calendar-data>` в тексте появляются переносы строк. То есть слово разрывается и продолжается с новой строки. Не могу понять с чем это связано и как победить?
Если смотреть тоже событие через приложение календарей, то строки отображаются корректно, а когда я получаю ответ с сервера, текстовые строки имеют перенос там, где его быть не должно.
Запрос к серверу делаю при помощи `HttpWebResponse.GetResponse();`
далее `XmlDocument.Load(ResponseStream)`
мыслей нет что не так. Подскажите пожалуйста?